# How to Handle great grand child windows in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

In my application, I am handling great grand child windows. Windows are coming in recursive manner like window A-> click on A -> window B opens -> click on B -> window C opens -> click on C window -> window D opens.
So I am storing windows in List and using if, else if conditions so that insertion can be maintained but while executing code some time it is switching to all windows and sometimes it is not switching to great grand child window. My code is mention as below.

```
public class DDE_finnone {


WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
String app_id= "1894562";

@BeforeTest
public void setupapplication(){

    File filepath = new File("C:\\Automation_Softwares\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", filepath.getAbsolutePath());

    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    java.util.ResourceBundle.clearCache();

    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    driver.get("http://retail.herofincorp.com:7031/finnsso/gateway/SSOGateway?requestID=7000002");
}

@Test
public void DDE() throws Throwable{

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    /*---------------------------------- CAS MAIN SCREEN ------------------------*/

    List<String> browsertabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

    System.out.println(browsertabs);

    driver.switchTo().window(browsertabs.get(0));

    driver.findElement(By.name("TxtUID")).sendKeys("testname");

    driver.findElement(By.name("TxtPWD")).sendKeys("Testpwd");

    driver.findElement(By.name("DataAction")).click();

    // Screenshotpath = fn_screenshot(Screenshotpath);

    try {

        if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) != null) {

            String alertmessage = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();

            System.out.println(alertmessage);

        }
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Screenshotpath = fn_screenshot(Screenshotpath);

    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

    driver.findElement(By.name("btnCAS")).click();

    driver.switchTo().window(browsertabs.get(0));

    /*-------------------------- Retail Screen ----------------------*/

    List<String> FinnoneCAS1 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

    Collections.sort(FinnoneCAS1);

    System.out.println(FinnoneCAS1);

    driver.switchTo().window(FinnoneCAS1.get(0));

    String title5 = driver.getTitle();

    System.out.println(title5);

    if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone SSO")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(FinnoneCAS1.get(1));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("frameForwardToApp"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("banner"));

    WebElement areasection = driver.findElement(By.id("selBranch"));

    areasection.clear();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    areasection.sendKeys("delhi");

//  Thread.sleep(2000);

    areasection.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

    Thread.sleep(3000);

//  Screenshotpath = fn_screenshot(Screenshotpath);

    driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

    driver.switchTo().frame("contents");

    Actions move_AutoLoan1 = new Actions(driver);

    WebElement Auto_loan1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Auto Loan"));

    move_AutoLoan1.moveToElement(Auto_loan1).build().perform();

    WebElement DDEsearch = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Detail Data Entry"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(DDEsearch));     

//  WebElement allsearch = driver.findElement(By.linkText("All"));

//  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(allsearch));

    DDEsearch.click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("main"));

    WebElement searchappId = driver.findElement(By.id("txtApplication"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchappId));

    // Excel should start

    searchappId.sendKeys(app_id);

//  Screenshotpath = fn_screenshot(Screenshotpath);

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement searchbtn = driver.findElement(By.name("btnSearch"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchbtn));

    searchbtn.click();

    WebElement linkappid = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='TABLEATTRIBUTES']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(linkappid));

    linkappid.click();

    driver.switchTo().window(FinnoneCAS1.get(0));   

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


    /*-------------- DDE ------------------------------------*/

    List<String> DDEscreen = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

    Collections.sort(DDEscreen);

    System.out.println(DDEscreen);

    driver.switchTo().window(DDEscreen.get(2));

    System.out.println(DDEscreen.get(2));

    String title2 = driver.getTitle();

    System.out.println(title2);

    if (title2.equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone SSO")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(DDEscreen.get(1));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    } else if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone CAS")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(DDEscreen.get(0));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

    WebElement demographic = driver.findElement(By.id("apy_b0i2text"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(demographic));

    demographic.click();

    WebElement customername = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='TABLEATTRIBUTES']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(customername));

    customername.click();

    WebElement personaltab = driver.findElement(By.id("apy_b1i1font"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(personaltab));

    System.out.println(personaltab.getText());

    WebElement qualification = driver.findElement(By.id("selEduQualification"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(qualification));

    qualification.sendKeys("Graduate");

    qualification.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

    /*------------ Education window ------------*/

    List<String> educationwindow = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

    Collections.sort(educationwindow);

    System.out.println(educationwindow);

    driver.switchTo().window(educationwindow.get(3));

    String title6 = driver.getTitle();

    System.out.println(title6);

    if (title6.equalsIgnoreCase("1894562-----NISHANT  OMAR")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(educationwindow.get(0));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    } else if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone SSO")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(educationwindow.get(1));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    } else if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone CAS")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(educationwindow.get(2));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

    WebElement searchcriteriaGo = driver.findElement(By.name("B1"));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchcriteriaGo));

    searchcriteriaGo.click();

    driver.switchTo().window(educationwindow.get(0));

    /*-----------------Return from Education Window  -----------------------*/

    List<String> returneducationdetails = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

    Collections.sort(returneducationdetails);

    System.out.println(returneducationdetails);

    driver.switchTo().window(returneducationdetails.get(2));

    System.out.println(returneducationdetails.get(2));

    String title21 = driver.getTitle();

    System.out.println(title21);

    if (title21.equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone CAS")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(returneducationdetails.get(0));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    } else if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Finnone SSO")) {

        driver.switchTo().window(returneducationdetails.get(1));

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you consider providing the following info: 1. Selenium version? 2. IEDriverServer version? 3. IE version? 4. Error stack trace. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium there is no any hierarchy in windows. Parent and child windows are named so just for our convention. But from selenium's perspective everything is just an another Window.

Below code gives some idea,

```
//Get the current window address
Set<String> parent = driver.getWindowHandle();

//Get the all window addresses that are opened by selenium. This includes the parent window too
Set<String> all = driver.getWindowHandles();


//Assume this is the element you need to interact and it is present in some window.
String XPATH = ".//";

//Now iterate through all windows and search for the element you need to interact with.
for(String now:all)
{

    driver.switchTo().window(now);
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(XPATH)).size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("Element found in the window "+now+ " "+driver.getTitle());
        //DO YOUR ACTUAL STUFF
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou Santhosh, but i think List is more reliable than Sets.

Comment: For window handles...  set is preferred because list might have duplicated but set wont have any duplicates.

Comment: i agree that list might store duplicate values but For Windows.. window ids/codes would be generated unique on run time so when we can save the windows as list for more than 3 windows at least to maintain insertion and output order, my script is working with this logic but some times it is get failure due to 7-8 recursive child windows are coming. I used Set but that were not working as like List is working , please provide me another solution so that same script can be executed successful always.

Comment: If list is working good for you... Then kindly go with that...Hope your issue is resolved now.

Comment: Santhosh,  But always it is not handling great grand child windows, my query is unresolved. please provide me the solution so that same can be executed 100 % successful in every execution.

Comment: are you using driver.getwindowhandles after opening all windows?

Comment: Yes,Script is mention in my query.

Comment: Totally how many windows are opened (including grand child) and what is size of the list you are getting by windowhandles?

Comment: 4(including great grand child window) and 3 for (grand child window)

Comment: so totally 7 windows.. And i hope all the windows are in same browser mode... And what is the size of the list... You can find it by listname.size()

Comment: listname.size() is 3 for Grand child window(Parent+Child+grand child), i think is correct.

Comment: Kindly open all the windows(make a note of windows count manually) and use windowhandles to get all the windows.. If the count doesnt match then you are doing something wrong...

Comment: windows counts are same

Comment: Issue is suppose if i execute my script 10 times then 6-7 times it is properly handling windows and rest 3 times it is not handling so please provide me the solution for always successful execution because if logic was not correct then script should not working even for a single execution but it is working but why not every time.

Comment: @NishantOmar This is the way we use window handles.. What is the error message it shows when the test fails. Also try running this codes inside try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //parent window=1
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("path")).click();

String mainwinid = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //parent+child window
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path")).click();

Set<String> childparentwinid = driver.getWindowHandles();
childparentwinid.remove(mainwinid);
    driver.switchTo().window((String)childparentwinid.toArray()[0]);

     //parent + child + grand child
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path")).click();

Set<String> AllIds = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(AllIds);

ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(AllIds);  
 String ChildWindowID = al.get(2);  
driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindowID);

   //perform action on grand child window
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path")).click();
```